# Resizing LUKS encrypted partition - had success but can't use the unallocated space now?

Tags: partition, luks

Following various guides online, I've attempted to reduce my LUKS-encrypted hard-drive partition (specifically, root / data). I've gotten to the point where GParted recognizes the new unallocated space, but it is "stuck inside" the original partition. In the screenshot below, you can see how the unallocated space is just 1 MB (nothing), but the highlighted data partition is half unallocated internally:

[image: GParted Overview]

And if you ask what's-up with the data partition, it says it has the unallocated space I want:

[image: GParted Warning]

So I queue up a resize where I shrink it to to its minimum size (~250 GB), and it shows me this beautiful preview of exactly what I **want** (giving me the ~198 GB unallocated as a separated partition):

[image: Goal]

But when I execute the resize, it fails as shown:

[image: Failure]

It thinks it's already the reduced size? But gah, it doesn't give me that "unallocated space" as a partition! The beautiful preview above reverts back to the first screenshot in this post.

I have also tried the KDE Partition Tool and it behaves basically the same way. Additionally, **I've tried carrying out the resize from a separate live disk so that the partition I'm resizing isn't mounted, and again, same exact behavior.** Another interesting point is what the Disks utility thinks:

[image: Disks Utility]

I am definitely not experienced with disk management so I have of course backed up my data and am considering just wiping the machine and making the partition smaller from the start, but I feel like I'm very close here? Is there a simple step missing or is this far from done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that while you resized the filesystem inside of the partition, the partition itself was not resized. Think of it like putting your foot inside of a shoe that fits perfectly. You have made your foot (the filesystem) smaller, but the shoe (partition) is the same size, thus there is unused space in the shoe. You need to get a smaller shoe.

A partition is just a concept stored in the GPT (GUID Partition Table). It stores the start position and end position of the partition. You need to compute the new end partition of the partition and update the GPT.

The formula is *NEW_PARTITION_SECTOR_END = PARTITION_SECTOR_START + (LUKS_SIZE_SECTORS + LUKS_OFFSET_SECTORS) - 1*. This I got from https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Resizing_LVM-on-LUKS#Resize_the_partition

In your case, you want to do "sudo parted /dev/nvme0n1" and then use the "resizepart" command. You can get the values of PARTITION_SECTOR_START from parted itself with the print command. The LUKS_OFFSET_SECTORS and LUKS_SIZE_SECTORS can be obtained from "cryptsetup status cryptdata". Add them all together and that will give you the new end value.

Important: Note that when you use parted, make sure to type the "unit" command first to change the units to "s" which stands for sectors.